# Linux only - BadPaddingException : Decryption error

Tags: java, docker, encryption, cryptography

I generated Public and Private key on my Windows computer using this Java code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
KeyPair myKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

In my program I also have next code:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(publisher);
Cipher decriptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
decriptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] ansData = decriptCipher.doFinal(decodedString);
```

This code successfully works on my Windows PC and on my MacOS PC, but somehow it doesn't work in my Docker container, and on my Ubuntu Server, where I launched program manually. Is it problem in OS or can it be related with my mother board crypto module?

P.S. Additional:

Also I have this in the Main:

```
static {
   int position = Security.getProviders().length;
   Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), position);
}
```

P.S. Exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:488)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:284)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:372)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a **complete** [mre].

Comment: Well, it is almost certain that the hardware or OS is not to blame. The Bouncy Castle provider is last and won't be used, which is reflected in the exception (obviously the Sun provider is used). The most likely reason is simply a bad ciphertext / private key combination, i.e. the plaintext was encrypted with the wrong public key.